# How can I check if an ArrayList contains any element of another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there any way to determine whether an ArrayList contains any element of a different ArrayList?

Like this:

```
list1.contains(any element of list2)
```

Is looping through all the elements of `list2` and checking the elements one by one the only way?

Comment: If 'X contains an element of Y' is the main usecase for your collection, you may want to consider using Set instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although not highly efficient, this is terse and employs the API:

```
if (!new HashSet<T>(list1).retainAll(list2).isEmpty())
    // at least one element is shared
```

Answer (score 64):

Consider the following:
[Java SE 7 documentation: java.util.Collections.disjoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29)

The "disjoint" method takes two collections (listA and listB for example) as parameters and returns "true" if they have no elements in common; thus, if they have any elements in common, it will return false.

A simple check like this is all that's required:

```
if (!Collections.disjoint(listA, listB))
{
  //List "listA" contains elements included in list "listB"
}
```

Comment: very useful method 1.7 onwards... :D

Comment: I prefer this answer as it uses native Java methods only and there is no casting required.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!CollectionUtils.intersection(arrayList1, arrayList2).isEmpty()){
      // has common
}
else{
   //no common
}
```

use **`org.apache.commons.collections`**

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to Apache Commons, see [CollectionUtils.intersection(a,b)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#intersection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29)

Use like this:

```
! CollectionUtils.intersection(list1, list2).isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 3):

How about trying like this:-

```
List1.retainAll(List2)
```

like this:-

```
int a[] = {30, 100, 40, 20, 80};
int b[] = {100, 40, 120, 30, 230, 10, 80};
List<Integer> 1ist1=  Arrays.asList(a);
List<Integer> 1ist2=  Arrays.asList(b);
1ist1.retainsAll(1ist2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not constrained in using third-party libraries, Apache commons [ListUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html) is good for common list operations.

In this case you could use the `intersection` method

```
if(!ListUtils.intersection(list1,list2).isEmpty()) {
    // list1 & list2 have at least one element in common
}
```